# Invalid procedure call or argument IE issue when iterating through document.styleSheets using $.each()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, each, jquery-1.3.2

I've written this code that iterates over all global style sheet rules and stores them in an array/object. I use this dictionary-like object later to change global rules rather than setting styles on individual elements.

Following code breaks in IE8 but works fine in Firefox3.7 and Chrome4.

```
var allRules;

$(function() {
    var fileRules;
    allRules = [];
    $.each(document.styleSheets, function() {
        // get rules for any browser (IE uses rules array)
        fileRules = this.cssRules || this.rules;
        $.each(fileRules, function() {
            allRules[this.selectorText] = this;
        });
    });
});
```

I get `Invalid procedure call or argument` error. When I try to debug it, this code sucessfully iterates through two CSS style sheet files with rules but when the second one's iteration is done, it fails.

I can't seem to find an error in this code.

Comment: Since you're not using `allRules` as an array, you should instead declare it as an object: `allRules = {};`

Comment: @Tim Down: tried that as well but it didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said that it wouldn't fix anything. It was just an aside.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The problem

After thorough testing I found out that `document.styleSheets` isn't a regular array in IE. That's why it breaks in `$.each()` call when it reaches the end.

If we take a look at jQuery function itself it has a `for` loop to iterate over an object that has a `length` property, falsely believing it's an array. `document.styleSheets` does have `length` property, but it's obviously not an array. So when this `for` loop in `$.each()` is executed:

```
for (var value = object[0];
     i < length && callback.call( value, i, value ) !== false;
     value = object[++i]){}
```

it fails after the last element has been iterated over. As we may see this `for` loop doesn't increment `i` on its own but rather increments it while assigning a new value to `value`.

We can check this manually as well. Write these two lines in any browser's address bar:

```
javascript:var a=[1,2,3];alert(a[3]);void(0);
javascript:alert(document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length]);void(0);
```

The first one runs fine in all browsers, but the second one fails in IE.

### The solution

We have to rewrite the iteration over style sheets

```
var allRules;

$(function() {
    var fileRules;
    allRules = {};
    // can't use $.each() over document.styleSheets because it's not an array in IE
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
    {
        fileRules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules || document.styleSheets[i].rules;
        $.each(fileRules, function() {
            allRules[this.selectorText] = this;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Great documentation of the problem and solution. +1

Comment: @Greg: I thought it might be useful to someone else as well so I documented it more thoroughly. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that parsing rule itself is failing?  Try experimenting with different stylesheets and reorder the rules to ensure that there isn't a problem parsing the rule for some reason.

Comment: but I'm not parsing the rule in any way shape or form... I'm just storing their names and rules against them...

Answer (score -2):

code true is:

```
var fileRules;
(function ($) {
    allRules = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        fileRules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules || document.styleSheets[i].rules;
        $.each(fileRules, function () {
            allRules[this.selectorText] = this;
        })(jQuery);
    }
});
```

Comment: This code surely doesn't work... Sorry. You're adding `(jQuery)` to `$.each`... Why did you add it in the first place? You probably wanted to make the main function immediately executable. But even though... Then this code should run the last in the document. Using solution's approach by running this on document ready is much more transparent. Don't you think so?

Comment: Not to mention the fact that you've made `allRules` a closure variable, so you won't be able to access those rules you've read into...